# error: unexpected element <service> found in <manifest>

Tags: android, cordova, service, android-manifest

I'm trying to build my Cordova app with a plugin created by me. This plugin contains a service that runs in the background, and I am not able to compile the app with it.
This is the error that the console shows me when I do cordova build android:

> What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed C:\Users\dev\Desktop\appTest\platforms\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:10:9-101: AAPT: error: unexpected element `<service>` found in `<manifest>`

My plugin.xml config:

```xml
<config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest/application">            
    <service android:name=".ForegroundService" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true"></service>
</config-file>

<config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
</config-file>
```

Any ideas?

My Cordova version is 10.0.0

Comment: Maybe add you plugin xml config

Comment: Either with the config-file tag empty or with the permissions and the service that the plugin needs to work, when I do cordova build it gives the error that I put before.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` to the root widget tag of config.xml

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you put the `<service>` inside `<application>`

See more here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element